# Simulate unplug and re-plug via command line for device development

Tags: command-line, udev

I am working on a couple projects and frequently they lock up where the only fix is to unplug and replug them in. I would like to be able to use the terminal to do this as it happens frequently with one of my projects, and will be useful longterm.

Comment: I feel like the reason they stop working might be hardware related, in which case disabling them wouldn't help.

Comment: i would like to try different avenues, and this is one of them :)

Comment: Well, you might be able to use `xinput`. See if it finds them: `xinput list`. No sudo necessary.